# 500 Error with laravel when creating a new project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan, http-status-code-500

I try to learn laravel and after creating a project with.

i created a new project by typing "laravel new projectname" in cmd, installing composer and node.js, changed in cmd to the project directory and installed composer there and tryed to run "php artisan serve" comand. i got the message "Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000"

when i open http://127.0.0.1:8000 i get a 500 Error (not from the browser. the error is from laravel).

I have absolutly no idea what could be wrong. I went by 3 guides for starters and they did not have this problem.

Is there anything i can do ti fix this error?

thank you very much in advance

edit: here is the logfile from storage/logs

```
[2019-10-12 20:13:12] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:44)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\helpers.php(424): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(NULL)
#1 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php(48): tap(NULL, Object(Closure))
#2 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php(24): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->key(Array)
#3 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(800): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array)
#4 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(682): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#5 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(630): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('encrypter', Array)
#6 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(768): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
#7 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(946): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('encrypter')
#8 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(874): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#9 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(835): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#10 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(682): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#11 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(630): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#12 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(768): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array)
#13 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(215): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...')
#14 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(189): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminateMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#15 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\public\\index.php(60): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#16 C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\Users\\\\Rjinxi...')
#17 {main}
"}
```

Comment: When you get this line `Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000` and I assume you don't close the terminal window, and you try to access the page in the browser, what gets printed out in the CMD?

Comment: [Sat Oct 12 22:11:36 2019] 127.0.0.1:61786 [200]: /favicon.ico

Comment: php artisan key:generate

Comment: None of those three guides was the official docs? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x#configuration "The next thing you should do after installing Laravel is set your application key to a random string."

Comment: this fixed it with the steps from Rippon Uddin. thank you

Answer (score 1):

So close your terminal session and run this command in your CMD:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

in the project folder. Make sure you have `.env` file created. Then `serve` your application once again.

Comment: same result. the .env file is empty.
Still getting this error in the log:
[2019-10-13 07:03:58] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at C:\\Users\\Rjinxil\\testproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:44)
[stacktrace]

Comment: `.env` should not be empty! You have to have `APP_KEY` at least with the generated key. Take a look at the `.env.example` file that comes with the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below steps :

```
php artisan config:cache

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: this fixed it after renmaing the .env.example file to .env

Comment: you should use those command while u created new project or move one local server to another or live. .env must be required too.